# Matlab random sampling

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to exercise myself in Matlab. I am trying to select randomly two lines from a file named data.dat.

My data.dat file looks like this:

```
12 4 6.1 7

14 4 8.4 62

7 56.1 75 98

9.7 54 12 35

2 4 8 7.8
```

To select 2 lines randomly from the data.dat here is how I am proceeding:

```
close all;
clear all;
%----------------------%
% Choose random lines
%----------------------%
M  = load('data.dat');
N=2; %number_of_lines
file_number = 2; %save each two lines in new file: selection_1, selection_2
```

Now I am saving the two selected lines in new files sequentially.

```
for k = 1:file_number
 i = randi(length(M),N);
 B=M(i,:)
 filename=['samples_',int2str(k),'_mc.dat']
 save (filename, 'B', '-ascii')
 clear B;
 end
```

I don't know why but I have more than 2 lines in each new files. Could you please explain me where did I made a mistake.

Comment: what does `i = randi(length(M),N);` give you for `i`? and does M(i,:) make 2 lines?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a mistaking when you generate the random numbers, as indicated by GameOfThrows.

```
i = randi(length(M),N); % gives you a matrix NxN of numbers
i = randi(length(M),[N,1]); % gives you a column of N numbers
```